# How to refactor same return type in c# in regard of coupling?

Tags: c#, validation, refactoring

In case of costume validation in web api I am using FluentValidation. The error codes has been developed in separate class but the thing which I am struggling with, is having same "return" but different function signature. Should I continue as it is now or should I make a new function for that return part and call it instead of repeating the return body part?If I need to define a new function, Could you please help me to make it work?

.NotNull() , .WithErrorCode() and .WithMessage() are from  FluentValidation.

```
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, byte?> NullableByteRequiredValidation<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, byte?> rule)
    {
        return rule
            .NotNull()
            .WithErrorCode(ErrorCodes.FieldRequired.Key)
            .WithMessage(string.Format(ErrorCodes.FieldRequired.Value, "{PropertyName}"));
    }
    #endregion Byte validations


    #region DateTime validations

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor for DateTimeRequiredValidation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rule"></param>
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, DateTime?> DateTimeRequiredValidation<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, DateTime?> rule)
    {
        return rule
            .NotNull()
            .WithErrorCode(ErrorCodes.FieldRequired.Key)
            .WithMessage(string.Format(ErrorCodes.FieldRequired.Value, "{PropertyName}"));
    }
```

[image: Error message class]

[image: Error message function]

Comment: Please paste code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change signature without changing return statement then you can:

1. If it is normal type, then you mas use base types for both types (old and new one), so signature will stay the same for noth returns.
2. If return type is generic, you have to make covariant, see [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Anyway, you will have to chagne function signature, but you are able to keep one function and not create another one.